# Looking For Things in Lists, In Inputs

Tags: python, list, input

I am currently making a password checker on Python 3.3.2 and I am currently looking for things inside the users input by doing this:

```
if ("A" in PassCheck) or ("B" in PassCheck) or ("C" in PassCheck) or ("D")in 
PassCheck) or ("E" in PassCheck) or ("F" in PassCheck) or ("G" in PassCheck) 
or ("H" in PassCheck) or ("I" in PassCheck) or ("J" in PassCheck) or ("K" in 
PassCheck) or ("L" in PassCheck) or ("M" in PassCheck) or ("N" in PassCheck 
 or
("O" in PassCheck) or ("P" in PassCheck) or ("Q" in PassCheck) or ("R" in 
PassCheck) or ("S" in PassCheck) or ("T" in PassCheck) or ("U" in PassCheck)
or ("V" in PassCheck) or ("W" in PassCheck) or ("X" in PassCheck) or ("Y" in 
PassCheck) or ("Z" in PassCheck):
```

Is there a way to do this with a list?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: At least put some efforts first :-(

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [string](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html) library to search for the presence of uppercase characters by using the [string.ascii_uppercase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) module

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
```

You can then use the [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function to test for the presence of uppercase characters for a given string input.

```
>>> Pass_Check_1 = 'ThisOneWorks'
>>> any(i in Pass_Check_1 for i in string.ascii_uppercase)
True

>>> Pass_Check_2 = 'thisonedoesntwork'
>>> any(i in Pass_Check_2 for i in string.ascii_uppercase)
False
```